# Hot water pipe falling off

Tags: pipe, hot-water

Any suggestions on how to fix this hot water tank pipe (tightly setup) falling off - am planning to call in a plumber [image]

Comment: If that is the exhaust for a gas water heater, it may be leaking dangerous exhaust fumes

Comment: @izzy - a pvc exhaust pipe?

Comment: With glue pipe joints, it is usually more of a replace job than a repair job.  Cut out bad section and use couplings and new pieces to replace.  The top short pipe might give problems.  If it is a gas exhaust pipe(might be) get it fixed now.

Comment: @Tim I'm out of my area of expertise here, but I thought I had seen those before. I may be mis-interpreting the results, but a web search makes me think it is a possibility. Just erring on the side of caution.

Comment: @izzy  Do think the newer hi-efficiently gas heaters do use PVC exhaust pipes.  Unfortunately the exits do tend to freeze over and get blocked, in places that get fking cold